# document.createElement() getting ignored

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, appendchild

I've built a simple program to learn OOP in Javascript. It merely outputs predefined string statements. The problem here is that the program is binding text nodes directly to the "output div", while *ignoring* the previous command to append them to respective "p" elements.

```
Student.prototype.sayHello = function()
{
    var responseString = document.createTextNode("Hello, I've been waiting here for you. Student.");
    return document.createElement("p").appendChild(responseString);
}
Student.prototype.sayGoodBye = function()
{
    var responseString = document.createTextNode("tchau");
    return document.createElement("p").appendChild(responseString);
}

var student = new Student();
document.getElementById("output").appendChild(student.sayHello());
document.getElementById("output").appendChild(student.walk());
document.getElementById("output").appendChild(student.sayGoodBye());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that [`appendChild(child)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) returns `child` but it seems you're expecting to return the added `p` element.

Try doing

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.appendChild(responseString);
return p;
```